# Finder sync extension unloaded while using redirection from Safari

Tags: objective-c, macos, findersync

I have simple application that enables URL scheme for redirections. Additionally application uses Finder Sync extension. After first time when application is opened  and Finder extension is loaded the redirection that comes from Safari (with chrome works corretly) unloads the Finder extension. Is there any particular reason for such behaviour and is there a way to block unload?